# XML parsing semicolon expected - only when replacing & with &amp

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I have the following query, which works:

```
DECLARE @Combined VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Combined = 'mac cheese';

DECLARE @KeyTable TABLE (Keyword VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @KeyTable
SELECT @Combined

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Keyword
    INTO #Temp
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Keyword,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM @KeyTable
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n);

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

When I try to add an ampersand to the `@Combined` it gives a special character error:

```
DECLARE @Combined VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Combined = 'mac & cheese';

DECLARE @KeyTable TABLE (Keyword VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @KeyTable
SELECT @Combined

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Keyword
    INTO #Temp
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Keyword,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM @KeyTable
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n);

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

So I added some code to replace the ampersand with `&amp` and I get a semicolon error:

```
DECLARE @Combined VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Combined = 'mac & cheese'

SET @Combined = REPLACE(@Combined, '&', '&amp')

DECLARE @KeyTable TABLE (Keyword VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @KeyTable
SELECT @Combined;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Keyword
    INTO #Temp
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Keyword,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM @KeyTable
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n);

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

I've attempted moving the semicolon to various locations and even adding more but it just won't work.  Any help anyone can provide would be appreciated!

Comment: All entity escape strings end with a semi-colon: `REPLACE(@Combined, '&', '&amp;')` - Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Comment: wow...so simple...thank you.  feel free to post as answer and I'll grant

Comment: @AlexK. No, one should not start to replace forbidden characters manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not start to replace special characters on your own!

Next time your string contains a `<` or a `->` and will break again.

Let `FOR XML PATH()` do the hard work for you:

```
SELECT 'This is pure text: ' + 'mac & cheese,<test1>,"test2"';
SELECT 'This is encoded: ' + (SELECT 'mac & cheese,<test1>,"test2"' AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''))
```

The result of the second: `This is encoded: mac &amp; cheese,&lt;test1&gt;,"test2"`

### UPDATE for your code:

The only thing you have to change, is to use `(SELECT ... FOR XML PATH())` instead of the *naked* `Keyword`

```
DECLARE @KeyTable TABLE (Keyword VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @KeyTable VALUES('mac & cheese,<test1>,"test2"');

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Keyword
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE((SELECT Keyword AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM @KeyTable
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n);
```

This will replace all forbidden characters implicitly...

The result

```
mac & cheese
<test1>
"test2"
```