# Seperated record when there is more than 1 value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I have to write a SQL query to produce seperate records if my column contains more than one value.

Like

```
select * 
from tblMachine 
where pkey = 1;
```

This is the result I got:

```
1 C000279   EMAIL PIC       xx@yy.com;yy@xx.com
```

I have a requirement to write a query so that it will produce seperate record if there are more than 1 value in the `email` column.

Like

```
1 C000279   EMAIL PIC       xx@yy.com
1 C000279   EMAIL PIC       yy@xx.com
```

Is this possible in SQL Server 2008?

@GurV, this is my exact query

```
select distinct c.PKEY [Customer Code],
c.NAME [Customer Name],
mi.MODEL [Machine #],
(select Split.a.value('.','varchar(100)') email
from 
    (select       
        cast('<x>' + replace(m.CONTACT_EMAIL,';','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as x
    from tblMachineContact m
    where mi.PKEY=m.MAC_PKEY and m.CONTACT_CATEGORY_PKEY in ('PC'))t
cross apply x.nodes ('/x') as Split(a)) [Customer Email]
from tblMachine mi
inner join tblCustomers on m.CUST_PKEY=c.PKEY
where mi.STATUS='A'
```

Comment: You should **NEVER EVER** store more than one value into a single column! This is a **HORRIBLY BAD** practice and violates even the first normal form of database design - **YOU DON'T DO IT!** If your `tblMachine` needs to have 1:n e-mails associated with it, you need to use a separate `tblEmail` table with a foreign key relationship to `tblMachine` - that's the proper relational design

Comment: I Think that what you want: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/04/21/sql-server-split-comma-separated-list-without-using-a-function/

Comment: @marc_s Dear LT268, I'm sure this question is bound to the need to do exactly this step towards normalisation (*deep pedagogical eye contact*)

Comment: @Shnugo: I sure *hope so!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You should not store multiple values in one single row and column. Consider normalizing your table structure.**

For now, you can do this using `cross apply` and `XML`. I used column names as col1, col2, ...  as you've not provided any schema details. Please change them as you need.

```
with your_table(col1     , col2   , col3, col4) as (
    select 1 ,  'C000279'  ,'EMAIL PIC' , 'xx@yy.com;yy@xx.com'
) 
--- test data. Don't mind the above. ---

select col1, col2, col3,
    Split.a.value('.','varchar(100)') email
from 
    (select 
        col1, col2, col3,
        cast('<x>' + replace(col4,';','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as x
    from your_table) t
cross apply x.nodes ('/x') as Split(a);
```

Produces:

[image]

#### EDIT:

Try this:

```
select distinct 
    c.PKEY [Customer Code],
    c.NAME [Customer Name],
    mi.MODEL [Machine #],
    m.email [Customer Email]
from tblMachine mi
inner join tblCustomers on m.CUST_PKEY=c.PKEY
left join (
    select
        MAC_PKEY,
        Split.a.value('.','varchar(100)') email
    from (
        select       
            MAC_PKEY,
            cast('<x>' + replace(m.CONTACT_EMAIL,';','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as x
        from tblMachineContact
        where CONTACT_CATEGORY_PKEY = 'PC'
    ) t cross apply x.nodes ('/x') as Split(a)
) m on mi.PKEY=m.MAC_PKEY
where mi.STATUS='A'
```

Comment: Bear in mind, that the simple XML-split will break, if there are forbidden characters (like the `&`-character) within the eMail address ([one related question about allowed characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-email-address)).

Comment: You might [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41105065/5089204) to find a secure way for escaping...

Comment: @GurV your code works for me, unfortunately i am using this part as a subquery inside main select statement. So when the subquery returns more than 1 value, the error occurs :(

Comment: @LT268 - Can you post the query you're trying to use in the question?

Comment: @GurV, i had posted my query in question. pls refer

Comment: @LT268 - You'll need a JOIN. Updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: That is a totally different question. You can directly do that without all this. You can use regular expressions to divide the column into two or more. I'd suggest you ask a new question for that.

Comment: @GurV- Great !! Working fine